# Height:100% in IE7

Tags: css, html, height

**UPDATE**

Margin for html and body needed to be 0 to fill page completely.

**END UPDATE**
**UPDATE**

I have fixed using the below suggestion of adding the height property to the html and body tags. Now there is a slight scroll down required to view the entire page. Ideas on why this is happening?

**END UPDATE**

I am using CSS to make a div fill the screen as needed. I've got width and height set to 100%, but the div doesn't fill the height of the screen. Is this a known issue with IE7 or am I possibly just missing something? Code below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="divy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#divy
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

Comment: Re your edit: have you implemented rlemon's answer? (That is, set the body's margin and padding to 0)

Comment: @MrLister That was the fix. I didn't notice the margin, padding addition at first glance, but it's all golden now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues is the container must have height of 100% for it's child element to assume 100%...

In this case the container is `<html>` -> `<body>` so a quick fix would be

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, #divy {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The element fills the height of the body element, which can be smaller than the browser window.

Set the height of the `html` and `body` elements, so that they fill the window:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: I've added the above code. I didn't consider the parent elements not being at 100%. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are defining a 100% height, it's ancestors or all subsequest ancestor, must have 100% as their height as well.

So, give 100% height, to the `body`, as well as `html`.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this issue with jQuery:

```
jQuery('.yourDiv').height(jQuery('body').height());
```